# change link of menu particular tab

Tags: menus, links, dashboard, theme-twenty-twelve

Wordpress theme - `Twenty Twelve.`

I want to change link of menu.

> Current --> No link.
>
> Required -->#about (link for particular tab only)

I've tried to change link from `menu tab` (Apperance --> Menu) but no use.

In header file I have this code:

```
<?php 
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );
?>
```

and In Manage location no menu is selected.

[image]

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have no menu selected.

In the *Manage location* screen select an existing menu and Save changes. If there is none, click on "Use new menu".

Then you should be able to edit it in the *Edit Menus* screen.

See [the Codex article on Menu Screens](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen)
and [the one on `wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Comment: but now, how this is working? means where is current menu code or any other things?

Comment: The menu code is generated by the `wp_nav_menu()` function (see the link added above by Johannes Pille for reference).
As you noticed, it is currently in your header.php file with "PRIMARY" as registered location. So the menu you will associate throught the *Manage Locations* screen will be the one generated in your header. If for a WP project you were needing several different menus, you would register several locations and associate each menu with its appropriate location in the *Manage Locations* screen. To learn more about how to do so, please read all wp_nav_menu Codex article.

Comment: thanx john. I added that link not johnnnes. i got my answer from that link. I tick mark your answer because your answer is relevant to my question. But your answer not complete.